# Going from Windows XP to Recently Installed Windows 10 - Nothing Works

Tags: windows, windows-10

Recently my computer was infected.  My computer expert installed Windows 10 (previously I was using Windows XP with no problems until I got the virus).  My computer tech said the computer works at his house.  However, I am having problems.  When I try to open a simple thing like google chrome it won't open.  After clicking the chrome icon it immediately puts the icon in the task bar at the bottom of the screen.  When I hover over it, I see a micro version of google chrome - if I try to maximize it does nothing.  Sometimes the icon flashes like it wants to open.

Could anyone help - I think it is a setting problem but when I click on settings the same thing happens - a micro version opens at the bottom of the screen - I don't know what to do?  Perhaps there is a compatability issue - I use a modem at my house - maybe the expert uses Wifi connection and that's why it works for him?????

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: *"I was using Windows XP with no problems until I got the virus."*  However, that is similar to saying *"Other than that Mrs. Lincoln, how was the play?"*  We are always glad to help, but you really should know that Windows XP officially stopped receiving security updates over three years ago.  When it comes to computers I am also a creature of habit, but nobody should be utilizing an operating system that isn't supported with security updates.  Your virus incident was inevitable.

Comment: @Run5k You're right, but OP already got rid of XP, so that's not very helpful.

Comment: I would probably suggest you get your computer tech person to come to your house to re-diagnose. If your computer was running Windows XP and is now running Windows 10 I would hazard a guess that your computer is quite old and is probably saturating any system memory/paging or that your hard disk may be slowly failing and the computer is trying to load the required resources to run the program(s). It may not be worth investing too much more money into this device if it is old.

Comment: That 'micro version' is a thumbnail of the window. So the window actually opens *somewhere*. Is it a desktop PC or a laptop?

Comment: @gronostaj, I appreciate the feedback but I also think that my statement is a bit more helpful than you seem to believe.  Educating an end-user regarding why they encountered their original problem can help avoid similar incidents in the future.  *"Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime."*

Comment: @gronostaj *OP already got rid of XP, so that's not very helpful*... I beg to differ. At least now the user knows what happened and hopefully it's a valuable lesson learned for the future similar situations. And because so many users aren't aware, it should be made policy to warn such users and stress that they're not the only ones at risk, it's everybody else's problem if it's connected to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to hazard a guess here, it looks like the window may simply be off the edge of the screen, which often causes maximize to fail.

Try right-clicking on the "micro" chrome, and selecting "Move", then hold the left arrow key, and then the up arrow key for about ten seconds each, and see if the window enters the visible area of the screen.

This can happen if your expert has a particularly large monitor, and chrome was outside the bounds of the new monitor.

Here is my attempt at an ASCII art representation of what I am suggesting:

```
|==========================|
| Your    |                |
| Monitor |    +------+    |
|         |    |Chrome|    |
|----------    +------+    |
|       Big Monitor        |
|==========================|
```